# no suitable constructor found for ArrayAdapter(MainListActivity.GetBlogPostsTask,int,String[])

Tags: java, android, android-arrayadapter

i'm getting this error while running this code, i'm following treehouse [Build a blog reader android app](https://teamtreehouse.com/library/build-a-blog-reader-android-app/exploring-the-masterdetail-template/blog-reader-project-overview-2)  and now i'm getting this error

> Error:(120, 52) error: no suitable constructor found for ArrayAdapter(MainListActivity.GetBlogPostsTask,int,String[])
>   constructor ArrayAdapter.ArrayAdapter(Context,int,int) is not applicable
>   (argument mismatch; MainListActivity.GetBlogPostsTask cannot be converted to Context)
>   constructor ArrayAdapter.ArrayAdapter(Context,int,String[]) is not applicable
>   (argument mismatch; MainListActivity.GetBlogPostsTask cannot be converted to Context)
>   constructor ArrayAdapter.ArrayAdapter(Context,int,List) is not applicable
>   (argument mismatch; MainListActivity.GetBlogPostsTask cannot be converted to Context)

now i'm getting error in this piece of code

```
private void udpateList() {
            if(blogData == null){
                // TODO: handle error
            }else{
                try {
                    JSONArray jsonPosts = blogData.getJSONArray("posts");
                    blogPostTitles = new String[jsonPosts.length()];
                    for (int i = 0; i < jsonPosts.length(); i++){
                        JSONObject post = jsonPosts.getJSONObject(i);
                        String title = post.getString("title");
                        title = Html.fromHtml(title).toString();
                        blogPostTitles[i] = title;
                    }
                    // !!!!!!!!!! getting error here !!!!!!!!!!!!!
                    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, blogPostTitles);
                    setListAdapter(adapter);
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Exception caught:", e);
                }
            }
        }
```

for easy understanding i've copied whole code, just in case i'm missing out something, i'm following the tutorials and the author is not getting any error while i'm getting error, what might be the problem

```
package com.example.android.treehouseblogs;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Html;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Toast;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.Reader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

public class MainListActivity extends ListActivity {

    protected String[] blogPostTitles;
    public static final int NUMBER_OF_POSTS = 20;
    public static final String TAG = MainListActivity.class.getSimpleName();
    protected JSONObject blogData;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_list);

        if(isNetworkAvailable()){
            GetBlogPostsTask getBlogPostsTask = new GetBlogPostsTask();
            getBlogPostsTask.execute();
        }else{
            Toast.makeText(this, R.string.network_not_availabel,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

    }

    private boolean isNetworkAvailable() {
        ConnectivityManager manager = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo networkInfo = manager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        boolean isAvailable = false;
        if(networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnected()){
            isAvailable = true;
        }
        return isAvailable;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main_list, menu);
        return true;
    }

    private class GetBlogPostsTask extends AsyncTask<Object, Void, JSONObject> {

        @Override
        protected JSONObject doInBackground(Object... params) {
            int responseCode = 1;
            JSONObject jsonResponse = null;
            try {
                URL blogFeedUrl = new URL("http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/api/get_recent_summary/?count=" + NUMBER_OF_POSTS);
                HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) blogFeedUrl.openConnection();
                connection.connect();
                responseCode = connection.getResponseCode();
                if(responseCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK){
                    InputStream inputStream = connection.getInputStream();
                    Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream);
                    int contentLength = connection.getContentLength();
                    char[] charArray = new char[contentLength];
                    reader.read(charArray);
                    String responseData = new String(charArray);
                    jsonResponse = new JSONObject(responseData);
                }else{
                    Log.i(TAG, "Unsuccessful HTTP Response Code:" + responseCode);
                }
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Exception caught:", e);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Exception caught:", e);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Exception caught:", e);
            }
            return jsonResponse;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject result) {
            blogData = result;
            udpateList();
        }

        private void udpateList() {
            if(blogData == null){
                // TODO: handle error
            }else{
                try {
                    JSONArray jsonPosts = blogData.getJSONArray("posts");
                    blogPostTitles = new String[jsonPosts.length()];
                    for (int i = 0; i < jsonPosts.length(); i++){
                        JSONObject post = jsonPosts.getJSONObject(i);
                        String title = post.getString("title");
                        title = Html.fromHtml(title).toString();
                        blogPostTitles[i] = title;
                    }

                    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, blogPostTitles);
                    setListAdapter(adapter);
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Exception caught:", e);
                }
            }
        }


    }
}
```

Comment: check my answer for detail understanding.

Answer (score 9):

Try: `MainListActivity.this` instead of `this`.

```
 ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainListActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, blogPostTitles);
```

The first parameter of the `ArrayAdapter` constructor that you're using is a `Context` object, in the context were you create the `ArrayAdapter`, `this` is a `MainListActivity.GetBlogPostsTask` object.

Comment: okay that worked, but what might be the reason, teacher is using "this" and it is working

Comment: @avinashizhere I've edited my answer and tried to explain the exception.

Comment: In general case, you should use NameActivity.this at the context parameter

Answer (score 2):

You have made this method `udpateList()` in your inner class `GetBlogPostsTask`
Therefore the first argument `this` will not work here

```
 new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, blogPostTitles);
```

Remove `this`, and use `MainListActivity.this` instead.

The overloaded constructor of `ArrayAdpater` class used here is supposed to be..  `ArrayAdapter(Context context, int resource, T[] objects)`

Now, `Context` cannot be just any java class, it needs to be an Android System specific resource:

According to [API docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html) :

> This is an abstract class whose implementation is provided by the Android system. It allows access to application-specific resources and classes

Answer (score 2):

`ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, blogPostTitles)`

When you write this code then the `this` refers to the inner class.
the context should be the activity class.
what i suggest is that you check your closing braces