# error: no suitable constructor found for ArrayAdapter(Tab1Fragment,int,ArrayList<String>)

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-fragments, android-arrayadapter

im new to programming and been trying add a list view + arrayadapter to a Fragment for a school project. Have referred to this question but to avail. [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32350275/no-suitable-constructor-found-for-arrayadaptermainlistactivity-getblogpoststask#*=*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32350275/no-suitable-constructor-found-for-arrayadaptermainlistactivity-getblogpoststask#_=_)

```
package com.tabian.tabfragments;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;    
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import android.widget.Button;


public class Tab1Fragment extends Fragment {
private static final String TAG = "Tab1Fragment";

private ListView listOfLeagues;
final ArrayList<String> listItems = new ArrayList<String>();

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab1_fragment,container,false);
    listOfLeagues = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.listOfLeagues);

    String[] values = new String[] { "World Cup", "Champions League" };

    for(int i = 0; i < values.length; i++){
        listItems.add(values[i]);
    }

    ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter<(Tab1Fragment.this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, listItems);
    listOfLeagues.setAdapter(adapter);

    listOfLeagues.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            String selectedLeague = listItems.get(position).toString();

            Intent titleIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), abc.class);

            titleIntent.putExtra("league", selectedLeague);
            startActivity(titleIntent);
        }
    });

    return view;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first argument to `ArrayAdapter` constructor ought to be a `Context` but you're passing a `Fragment` i.e. `Tab1Fragment.this`.

In a `Fragment` that is in attached state in its lifecycle, you can get a `Context` with `getContext()`. So, replace `Tab1Fragment.this` with `getContext()`.